# Validate email format without model - databasedotcom gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, databasedotcom-gem

I am new to Rails and I am using the salesforce gem, databasedotcom so there are is no model where I would normally validate the email address format, simple_form is validating presence but this error when an invalid email is entered:

```
Databasedotcom::SalesForceError at /leads
Email: invalid email address:def create
```

Here is the controller:

```
def create
 @lead = Lead.new(params[:lead])
 @lead['OwnerId'] = '005b0000000WxqE'   

 if @lead.save
   redirect_to @event
 else
   render "new"
 end
end
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @lead, url: leads_path(@lead, event_id: params[:event_id]), method: :post do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :FirstName, :label => "First Name" %>
 <%= f.input :LastName, :label => "Last Name" %>
 <%= f.input :Email %>
 <%= f.input :Company %>
 <%= f.button :submit, value: "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

I need to add something like 'if @lead.valid?' but im not sure what steps to take to make this work because that on its own doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an options for you,  [client_side_validations-simple_form](https://github.com/DockYard/client_side_validations-simple_form) gem has the simple_form with client_side_validation.

hope this helps